# How to add a description to security-group RULE

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-security-group

Adding a description to my Security_Group errors

In my terraform code I have a security_group that is pulling variables from a var.tf file.  when I try and add a description I get the redline under the code stating that it is not going to work. Greatly appricieated it someone could help me fix this syntax.

```
ingress {
from_port   = "${var.port["ssh"]}"
to_port     = "${var.port["ssh"]}"
protocol    = "tcp"
cidr_blocks = ["${var.cidr_groups["Kathmandu",description"Kathmandu"]}","${var.cidr_groups["Disney",description"Disney"]}"]
```

}

Comment: What makes you think that is the syntax for adding a description to a security group rule?

Comment: tmac, if you can provide the full `resource` definition from your code, it will make helping you easier. There are multiple ways to define a security group in Terraform for AWS.

Comment: It is best practice not to add rules to your security group, use aws_security_group_rule instead

Answer (score 1):

Based on your snippet, I believe you are using the `aws_security_group` resource. If that is the case then your snippet is not using the correct syntax. It looks like you have included the description in the CIDR blocks which is invalid.

You can include a description field at both the security group and the ingress/egress blocks.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh" {
   name = "ssh_access"
   description = "Security group to allow ssh access"
   vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

   ingress {
      from_port   = "${var.port["ssh"]}"
      to_port     = "${var.port["ssh"]}"
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["${aws_vpc.main.cidr_block}"]
      description = "ingress rule for ssh"
   }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that if you provide multiple security groups or CIDR blocks to an ingress/egress rule then they all get the same description.

Comment: ydaetskcoR thanks for the reply but I do not believe that is so,  you can add a description to each and every rule.

Comment: rclement that is what I am saying,  I need help with this syntax,  I know this is incorrect.  but how would I add the description in the format I have

Comment: What I put in my answer is the correct way to do it per the [documentation for security groups](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html). Run it and you will have a security group. If the top level `description` overwrites the ingress `description` then remove it.